# Getting slashes and letters while I only want number

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the following code to bring back prices from an ecommerce website:

```
response.css('div.price.regularPrice::text').extract()
```

but getting the following result:

```
'\r\n\t\t\tDhs 5.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t',
```

I do not want the slashes and letters and only the number 5. How do I get this?

Comment: use button `{}` to format code and results.

Comment: you can use `strip()` to remove tabs and enter, and later you can use slicing

Answer (score 2):

First you can use `strip()` to remove tabs `"\t"` and enters `"\n"`.

```
data = ['\r\n\t\t\tDhs 5.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
        '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']

data = [item.strip() for item in data]
```

and you get

```
['Dhs 5.00', '']
```

Next you can use `if` to skip empty elements

```
data = [item for item in data if item]
```

and you get

```
['Dhs 5.00']
```

If item always has the same structure `Dns XXX.00`
then you can use slicing `[4:-3]` to remove `"Dhs "` and `".00"`

```
data = [item[4:-3] for item in data]
```

and you get

```
['5']
```

So now you have to only get first element `data[0]` to get `5`.
If you need you can convert string `"5"` to integer `5` using `int()`

```
result = int(data[0])
```

---

You can even put all in one line

```
data = ['\r\n\t\t\tDhs 5.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
        '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']

data = [item.strip()[4:-3] for item in data if item.strip()]

result = int(data[0])
```

If you always need only first element from list then you can write it

```
data = ['\r\n\t\t\tDhs 5.00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
        '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']

result = int( data[0].strip()[4:-3] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to fetch only the numbers.

`\d+` regex expression should do the trick.